# Why is my calendar widget not allowing me to pick days after my original start day?

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I've built a calendar widget from scratch and I'm trying to implement a rule that will only allow users to click on/choose an end date that is after their selected start date.

I've stored both the start and end dates in the component's state and when I console log the start and end day everything looks fine. And when I remove the `day > this.state.selectedStartDay` from the if/else statement, it does allow me to choose dates that are after the start date (although it will also allow me to choose an earlier day in the same month, which is **not** the correct behavior).

When I run this code with the console log statement and without the `day > this.state.selectedStartDay` line of code in this if/else statement, I get the correct numbered start and end days (i.e. if I chose the 1st of Feb. and the 14th of Feb., the start day logs a 1 and the end day logs a 14). And when I run it with the `day > this.state.selectedStartDay` line of code, I get some strange behavior:

- It does restrict the user's choices to dates that are after the selected start date, but some of the dates that are *after* the start date become restricted as well (i.e. if I chose Feb. 4th, then any days from Feb. 10th onwards become restricted as well

I've done many console logs and the data itself seems to be correct, but I can't figure out why this behavior is happening. Help is appreciated!

```
  handleDateClick(month, day, yr) {
    let clicks = this.state.clicks + 1;
    let realMonthNum = month + 1;

    this.setState({ clicks });

    if (this.state.clicks % 2 === 0) {
      this.setState({ selectedStartMonth: realMonthNum });
      this.setState({ selectedStartDay: day });
      this.setState({ selectedStartYr: yr });
      this.resetEndDate();
    } else if (month >= (this.state.selectedStartMonth - 1) && day > this.state.selectedStartDay) {
      console.log('Start day: ' + this.state.selectedStartDay);
      console.log('End day: ' + day);
      this.setState({ selectedEndMonth: realMonthNum });
      this.setState({ selectedEndDay: day });
      this.setState({ selectedEndYr: yr });
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not sure why, but even using the `yr` in a comparison statement isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to use `setState` once when you finish your code logic. Do logic on local variables instead of using state immediately after you set it (`this.state.selectedStartMonth`)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the tip! I will keep that in mind!